scons generate compile_commands.json even on compile failure
I use scons and CLion. CLion uses the compile_commands.json file to know the contents of the project. I am migrating existing code into a Godot C++ module. I expect the compile to fail until I make the needed alterations but this would be easier with CLion code completion. This does not work until the files are listed in compile_commands.json. Is there a way to generate a compile_commands.json even when the source fails to compile?
I can do this by commenting out the code, but this step is a little slow.

Is using scons a non modifiable condition ?

I am writing a Godot C++ module, and I think it is non modifiable. They have a whole build system based on scons and my module is built using a sub-construct file. I've considered writing a simple script to wrap the code in comments when copying into the module. I also saw somewhere that prepending a target with "-" would allow some test jobs to continue on failure, but I am unsure if I can do that for this.

Scons have been undocumented for at least 10 years, I don't know why they chose to go with that. Unfortunately I cannot help you, I avoid Scons at all costs.

The technique of adding a leading dash to continue is described here: https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#action_objects but if you're not writing your own Action strings it's not much help, try @bdbaddog's suggestion (https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#opt-keep-going)

Try running scons -k <whatever other options you use>
-k = keep going
